# Embedded python: extern PyRun_SimpleString, Expected identifier

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, types, marmalade

I'm trying to run some python commands with an embedded interpreter in C++ (I'm using Marmalade middleware and compiling to arm; this is a ported version of python 2.6.4 which compiles to a library; I'm linking to the library and loading in the ported python headers)

[ fully ported code here: https://github.com/marmalade/python ]

My trouble is I don't know how to properly import the functions, I keep getting "type specifier" errors for PyRun_SimpleString

## Should I be specifying it as *void* instead of *int* or is it something else to do with PyAPI_FUNC(int) ?

**PythonTest.cpp (using libpython_d.a)**

```
#include "Python.h"

extern int PyRun_SimpleString(const char*);
extern void Py_Initialize(void);
extern void Py_Finalize(void);

int main() {
while(true){
Py_Initialize();

PyRun_SimpleString("print('Python Print test')");

Py_Finalize();
}
return 0;
}
```

---

```
error:
PythonTest.cpp(3): error : expected identifier before '__null' (col 48)
PythonTest.cpp(3): error : expected ',' or '...' before '__null' (col 48)
IntelliSense: expected a type specifier PythonTest.cpp 3
```

---

These are excerpts that reference the PyRun_SimpleString function and some relevant dependants. [Compiled in libpython_.a ; header directories are linked]

### pythonrun.h

```
#define PyRun_SimpleString(s) PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(s, NULL)
...
...
PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(const char *, PyCompilerFlags *);
```

### pythonrun.c

```
#undef PyRun_SimpleString
PyAPI_FUNC(int)
PyRun_SimpleString(const char *s)
{
    return PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(s, NULL);
}
```

### pyport.h

```
#ifndef PyAPI_FUNC
#   define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) RTYPE
```

Comment: Working example of what i'm trying to do [Pastebin-Marmalade library example](http://pastebin.com/QYLcU6DC)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. when you're importing functions from a library u HAVE to use the PyAPI functions

in this case it was

```
PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(const char *, PyCompilerFlags *);
```

Not the old macro variant

```
#define PyRun_SimpleString(s) PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(s, NULL)
```

To use this basically define an extern function to the Python API function you want; in this case to run a simple string, you must use simpleStringFlags, setting arg1 to your python string and arg2 to NULL.
ex:

```
PyRun_SimpleStringFlags("print('Hello form python library')",NULL);
```

here's a marmalade example:

### PyAppTest.mkb

```
#!/usr/bin/env mkb

librarys
{
    <arm_shared>
    "../pythonMaster,python"
}

files
{
    (source)
    PyAppTest.cpp
    (header)
    PyAppTest.h
}

includepaths
{

    ../pythonMaster/
    ../pythonMaster/upstream/Python
    ../pythonMaster/upstream/Include
}
```

### PyAppTest.cpp

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "../header/PyAppTest.h"
#include "s3eDebug.h"
#include "s3eDevice.h"
#include "s3eSurface.h"



void Py_Initialize();
void Py_Finalize();
int PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(const char *, PyCompilerFlags *);
char *Py_GetProgramFullPath(void);
const char *Py_GetVersion(void);
const char *Py_GetPlatform(void);
const char *Py_GetCopyright(void);
const char *Py_GetCompiler(void);
const char *Py_GetBuildInfo(void);

// Main entry point for the application
int main() {

    Py_Initialize();
    const char *fullPath= Py_GetProgramFullPath();
    const char *pyVer=Py_GetVersion();
    const char *pyPlat=Py_GetPlatform();
    const char *pyCopy=Py_GetCopyright();
    const char *pyCompiler=Py_GetCompiler();
    const char *pyBuild=Py_GetBuildInfo();
    PyRun_SimpleStringFlags("print('hello, this is python')",NULL);
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_Finalize();
     while (!s3eDeviceCheckQuitRequest())
    {
        // Fill background blue
        s3eSurfaceClear(0, 0, 255);

        // Print a line of debug text to the screen at top left (0,0)
        // Starting the text with the ` (backtick) char followed by 'x' and a hex value
        // determines the colour of the text.
s3eDebugPrint(10,20, fullPath, 0);
s3eDebugPrint(10,50, pyVer, 0);
s3eDebugPrint(10,100,  pyPlat, 0);
s3eDebugPrint(10,150, pyCopy, 0);
s3eDebugPrint(10,250, pyCompiler, 0);
s3eDebugPrint(10,350, pyBuild, 0);




        // Flip the surface buffer to screen
        s3eSurfaceShow();

        // Sleep for 0ms to allow the OS to process events etc.
        s3eDeviceYield(0);
    }
    // Return
    return 0;
}
```

### PyAppTest.h

```
extern int PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(const char *, PyCompilerFlags *);


extern void Py_Initialize(void);
extern void Py_Finalize(void);
extern char *Py_GetProgramFullPath(void);

extern const char *Py_GetVersion(void);
extern const char *Py_GetPlatform(void);
extern const char *Py_GetCopyright(void);
extern const char *Py_GetCompiler(void);
extern const char *Py_GetBuildInfo(void);
```